# HC SR501 PIR false triggers

Tags: microcontroller, pir

I'm using this circuit as one bit memory for PIR sensor state. This way I can read PIR triggers when I wake ESP8266 from deepsleep. The circuit is working fine, however I get false trigger each time ESP wakes from sleep or resets.  I managed to solve this issue by removing reverse polarity protection diode from PIR sensor and by adding a 100nf ceramic capacitor between pir GND and SIGNAL wires. Could someone explain me what is the role of diode removal in preventing false trigger (I came to this soludion by trial-error method).[image]

Comment: `The circuit is working fine, however I get false trigger each time ESP wakes from sleep` ... how can it be working fine when it fails to operate as expected?

Comment: It operates as expected when I removed the reverse polarity protection diode from pir sensor (this is not an issue for me) and added 100nf capacitor. I'd like to find an explanation why it works without false triggers after this mod. I understend that 100nf capacitor filters out the noise but why did the removal of this diode also helped ?

Comment: something to do with the PIR ... it is somehow charging the capacitor ... or the ESP is charging the capacitor through the MOSFET body diode

Comment: I tried disconnecting the pir SIGNAL wire from the rest of the circuit and it is triggered even in that case. Capacitor is not charged then.  I assume there is some interference from ESP powering on. This interference has stopped when I removed the pir diode and added 100nf capacitor.